# How can I use usepackage only in `\mathbb`?

Tags: math-mode, mathbb

I want to use these mathematical sets that are shown in the picture:

[image]

I used the following: `\usepackage{pxfonts}`, but then the whole context changed.

I want the original LaTeX font, but when I use the  `\mathbb{}`, show the ones in the image. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Please show us what you try so far. The best as small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. In preamble let it load only to your problem relevant packages.

Comment: Your question is not clear. The following example works as expected: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pxfonts}

\begin{document}
$\mathbb{Z Q C E N}$, $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$
\end{document}`. What problem(s) you have?

Comment: I think he wants to use the default font throughout the whole document, except when calling the ```\mathbb{}``` command, where he wants to use the font from the pxfonts package, which I think it is Palatino. This is very easily done with XeLaTex, if he is willing to compile with it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the package [`mathalpha`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha) with option `bb=px`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bb=px]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
\( \mathbb{ZQCEN} \)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much!!!!!
It works!!!!!!!